# Sum with latest date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL query

```
Select [Item No_][Expiration Date],[Manufacturing Date]
,([Lot No_] ),
Sum(Quantity)Quantity
from [Warehouse Entry] 
Group by [Lot No_],[Expiration Date],[Manufacturing Date],[Item No_]
```

Data is coming like this

```
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| Item No_ | Expiration Date | Manufacturing Date |   Lot No_    |         Quantity         |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| BRN00171 | 2020-05-01      | 2019-05-01         | A08E03 X 5   |   7.00000000000000000000 |
| BRN00171 | 2020-05-01      | 2019-05-01         | BLRDUM42 X 1 |   1.00000000000000000000 |
| BRN00171 | NULL            | NULL               | JULY10       | -69.00000000000000000000 |
| BRN00171 | 2011-04-01      | NULL               | JULY10       |  69.00000000000000000000 |
| BRN00171 | 2020-07-01      | 2019-07-01         | A16F15 X 24  |  24.00000000000000000000 |
| BRN00171 | 2020-01-01      | 2019-01-01         | FFWW         |  29.00000000000000000000 |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------+
```

How can i modify my code to achieve data like below?

```
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+----------+
| Item No_ | Expiration Date | Manufacturing Date |   Lot No_    | Quantity |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+----------+
| BRN00171 | 01-05-20        | 01-05-19           | A08E03 X 5   |        7 |
| BRN00171 | 01-05-20        | 01-05-19           | BLRDUM42 X 1 |        1 |
| BRN00171 | 01-07-20        | 01-07-19           | A16F15 X 24  |       24 |
| BRN00171 | 01-01-20        | 01-01-19           | FFWW         |       29 |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that, the below answer remove the third and fourth column.

```
with [Warehouse Entry]( [Item No_], [Expiration Date], [Manufacturing Date], 
[Lot No_], [Quantity] ) as
(
select 'BRN00019','2020-05-01','2019-05-01','A19F14 X 252',133 union all
select 'BRN00019','2020-05-01','2019-05-01','Jun-11',-12  union all
select 'BRN00019',null,null,'Jun-11',7  union all
select 'BRN00019','2011-04-01',null,'Jun-11',-7  union all
select 'BRN00019','2020-07-01','2019-07-01','Jun-11',12  union all
select 'BRN00019','2020-07-01','2019-07-01','A19F14 X 48',1 
) 
select [Item No_], [Expiration Date], [Manufacturing Date], [Lot No_], 
[Quantity]  from [Warehouse Entry] where [Expiration Date] in 
(select [Expiration Date] from [Warehouse Entry] where [Expiration Date] is 
not null )
and [Manufacturing Date] in (select [Manufacturing Date] from [Warehouse 
Entry] where [Manufacturing Date] is not null )
```

Comment: max will not work,because one lot with one item could have different expiry & manufacting dates

Comment: I have change example please see @SujatMirge

Comment: I have see the above changed example, exact what output you want.

Comment: I want third and fourth row to be removed in changed example

Comment: I have edit the answer as per your requirement check it

Answer (score 1):

I think, you're looking for eliminated zero quantities whenever grouped by `[Item No_]` & `[Lot No_]`

```
Select [Item No_],
       max([Expiration Date]) as [Expiration Date],
       max([Manufacturing Date]) as [Manufacturing Date],
       [Lot No_], 
       Sum([Quantity]) as Quantity 
  from [Warehouse Entry] 
 Group by [Item No_],[Lot No_]
 Having Sum([Quantity]) > 0;

Item No_    Expiration Date Manufacturing Date  Lot No_       Quantity
BRN00019    01-07-20        01-07-19            A19F14 X 252  133
BRN00019    01-07-20        01-07-19            A19F14 X 48   1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6a62fa9b2b81932b7ae70da9b348ce95)</kbd>

Comment: @user10991129 Did you try this? If it did not work, explain in a useful manner and not with a cryptic "not work" comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to check 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ae7fe036a72f446cb238f0edcca53e6f

Sample Data below:

```
with [Warehouse Entry]( [Item No_], [Expiration Date], [Manufacturing Date], [Lot No_], [Quantity] ) as
(
select 'BRN00019','01-07-20','01-07-19','A19F14 X 252',133 union all
select 'BRN00019',null,null,'Jun-11',-12  union all
select 'BRN00019','01-03-12',null,'Jun-11',7  union all
select 'BRN00019',null,null,'Jun-11',-7  union all
select 'BRN00019','01-03-12',null,'Jun-11',12  union all
select 'BRN00019','01-07-20','01-07-19','A19F14 X 48',1 
)
```

Use This....................................................

```
Select [Item No_],
       max([Expiration Date]) as [Expiration Date],`enter code here`
       max([Manufacturing Date]) as [Manufacturing Date],
       [Lot No_], 
       Sum([Quantity]) as Quantity 
  from [Warehouse Entry]
 Group by [Item No_],[Lot No_]
 Having Sum([Quantity]) > 0
 Order by [Manufacturing Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY [Expiration Date] DESC
```